# Print out progress reports of add1()

Tags: r, scope, regression, lm

I seem to have a hard time grasping how `add1()` works. First of all, in `add1()`, setting `trace = TRUE` prints out progress reports but my attempts to do this have failed several times. So how do we print out the progress reports of adding terms to the model so as to test for improved fit (or not)? Also, why the `LRT` (likelihood-ratio test) value is not in the output? Example as follows:

```
require(graphics); require(utils)
lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
add1(lm1, scope = .~. + .^2, test="Chisq", trace = TRUE)

#It seems that no progress report has been printed. Also `LRT` is missing
Single term additions

Model:
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality
                             Df Sum of Sq  RSS AIC Pr(>Chi)   
<none>                                    2105 191            
Agriculture:Examination       1      10.7 2094 192   0.6251   
Agriculture:Education         1       1.8 2103 193   0.8399   
Agriculture:Catholic          1      75.0 2030 191   0.1915   
Agriculture:Infant.Mortality  1       4.4 2101 193   0.7528   
Examination:Education         1      48.7 2056 192   0.2943   
Examination:Catholic          1      40.8 2064 192   0.3378   
Examination:Infant.Mortality  1      65.9 2039 191   0.2216   
Education:Catholic            1     278.2 1827 186   0.0099 **
Education:Infant.Mortality    1      93.0 2012 191   0.1451   
Catholic:Infant.Mortality     1       2.4 2103 193   0.8184   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```